# ng-repeat and string replace expression value

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, node.js, express

I am unable to find a solution to remove a substring in an angular expression while using the ng-repeat directive.

The controller is in an external javascript file, and html is as follows.

```js
function myController($scope, $http){
  $http.get('http://localhost:3000/people.json').
    success(function(data){
      $scope.persons = data;
    });
}
```

```html
<table ng-controller="myController" class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead class="text-center">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Address</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in persons" class="text-center">
      <td>((person.name}}</td>    
      <td>{{person.id}}</td>
      <td>{{person.address}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The localhost:3000/people.json page has a couple hundred JSON objects:

[
 {
   name: "John Smith",
   id: 12345,
   address: "addr:789 Broadway St"
 },

...
]

**My Question:** What is the most efficient and/or easiest method of stripping out the 'addr:' substring in the address value? I don't have write access to the people.json page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add a function to your controller. something like

```
$scope.stripAddr = function(address) {
  return address.substring(5);
}
```

and change your html to

```
<td>{{stripAddr(person.address)}}</td>
```

please excuse and errors in my javascript I use coffescript all time but I hope you get the idea

Comment: @roytheboy What happen if text change in future become  it become `address:` instead of `addr:`' or for writing the same logic for other requirement. may lead to rewrite the code.

Comment: @pankajparkar I was just trying to illustrate the principle and keep the javascript as simple as possible as I'm much happier with coffeescript. Its easy enough to change the javascript to parse the string properly.

Comment: @RoyTheBoy but playing with the index directly is not good thing

Comment: @pankajparket.  As I said I was just illustrating the principle, hence the 'something like'. Just replace substring(5) in my answer with value.split("addr:").pop(). The real difference in our answers is whether to use a filter or a controller function. I just find the later more versatile in general. For example 'addr' could be passed as data to the controller and used in my function.

Comment: @RoyTheBoy  I would prefer the filter, That will make more angularise thing..your solution is also good..but don't sound like generic & resusable?

Answer (score 0):

Use filter that could be the best way for you. You can reuse that filter any where, where you want to remove some matching string like here we use `addr`:

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in persons" class="text-center">
  <td>((person.name}}</td>    
  <td>{{person.id}}</td>
  <td>{{person.address}}</td>
</tr>
```

**JS**

```
.filter('matchreplace',function() {
        return function(value, matchstring){
            return value.split(matchstring).pop()
        }
    }
  );
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/1117/)

Thanks.

Comment: This also works. It looks a little cleaner in the html honestly, is there any significant performance difference between this and answer and the one RoyTheBoy provided?

Comment: Yes you can use it any where where you want to remove string like here we remove `addr:`..this is reusable code..and using specific index for replacing string not great deal..what happen if text changed to `address:` in RoyTheBoy answer

Comment: @dwrecked now you decide which is the better way to do it.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<td>{{person.address.substring(5)}}</td>
```