# truncate string in mvc homecontroller javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have a string coming in from the database say, ExpectedDate. I get the string in as `2015-07-08T00:00:00.` I want to be able to remove the `T00:00:00.`from the string. Is this possible in MVC from the homecontroller javascript? if so, how?

I've tried to use a replace function, but I can't find the replace method in the MVC javascript file. What am I doing wrong?

Please help!

Comment: What is meaning of MVC javascript file? is it .js file or .cshtml ?

Answer (score 0):

Controllers are not generally written in JavaScript in .NET. If you're going to do it in JavaScript client side, it would be much easier to load it into a Date object and then use the toDateString method with a format:

```
var d = new Date("2015-07-08T00:00:00")
d.toDateString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

If you have the .NET DateTime object before it writes to the client, then you can do

```
your_date_time_object.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326921/ng-repeat-and-string-replace-expression-value - but instead of reading from the front of the string, I obviously want to remove from the end of string

Comment: The example you're referencing uses AngularJs.  Are you using Angular or just MVC?